# Display text file contents through a linux absolute path in a JSP page using Jquery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, linux, jsp

So I was able to display the contents of a text file (file.txt) in a div (text) using different approaches:

First:

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {
$(".text").load("file.txt");
}, 100));
```

Second:

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {
 $.ajax({
     url : "file.txt",
     dataType: "text",
     success : function (data) {
         $(".text").html(data);
     }
 });
}, 100));
```

Third:

```
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {
$.get("file.txt", function(data) {
      $(".text").html(data);
}, 'text');
}, 100));
```

The problem is, if I have an exact copy under /home/user/file/file.txt and change those "file.txt" to "/home/user/file/file.txt", it doesn't work. By the way, I'm refreshing the div every 100 milliseconds, it works but if I changed it to absolute text file path, the contents are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a path of the user's hard disk to load a file with Ajax.

You need to use HTTP(S), and (unless you [take steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)) you have to use the same server as the HTML document in which the JS runs.

Make the file available from the web server and use the URL you give it there.